# rDNS ( reverse lookup ) error in pointing zimbra mail server

Tags: dns, digital-ocean, cloudflare, zimbra

We have an issue with rDNS for our mail server(zimbra), We hosted our mail server with DigitalOcean **(mail.examplecloud.com)** , and our webserver have A record with cloudflare**(example.com)** ,We created relevant records (A,MX,PTR,SPF,DMARC ) with cloudflare DNS configuration for **example.com** . When we check with MX tools report saying rDNS not found and other records are listed OK , PTR record for **example.com** automatically created and maintained by DigitalOcean which points webserver, where i need to place my PTR record to locate  **mail.examplecloud.com** to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

PTR records are used in process of determining the domain name associated with an IP address (so, the reverse of the usual "forward" DNS lookup of an IP address from a domain name).

Since the owner of the IP address is your hosting company, they are the only ones who can create valid PTR record.